# How to restore Active Desktop if Themes is locked via GPO?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, desktop-customization

My company forces Active Desktop upon everybody so that it can display a (monthly-rotated) corporate wallpaper.jpg.

Problem is, some computers (including my laptop) somehow experienced some errors resulting in the dreaded "Active Desktop Recovery" screen to show up... and clicking the "Restore My Active Desktop" button **always** resulted in "Internet Explorer Script Error".

Various workarounds I found in the Internet either does not work or requires me to change the theme first to something else... and the latter I can't do because the Desktop Settings screen is locked via GPO.

As it happens, due to the nature of the programs I use, I'm granted Administrator-level access on my computer.

The question is:

**How do I fix my situation?**

Note: I don't need to put on my own wallpaper, but watching the "Active Desktop Recovery" screen gets tiresome. I'm quite happy with the corporate wallpaper. I just need to somehow 'recover' my Active Desktop.

More information:

- OS: Windows XP Professional SP3 (yeah, company's too afraid to even experiment with Windows 7)
- Antivirus: Symantec Endpoint Protection

If you need any additional information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Been there. Both as a user and as admin who needed to fix it. I never figured it out, despite spending half a day on it. Every single solution seems to result in other errors or in no result. I ended up re-imaging the whole laptop. That still bugs me half a decade later.

Comment: Active Desktop isn't needed to rotate wallpaper... why not just use BgInfo?

Comment: @InterLinked it _was_ a "Corporate-mandated wallpaper", as I have explicitly stated in the **very first line** of my question. I no longer work there, but IIRC it was some JPG image not BMP image, and IIRC WIndows XP did not support JPG images for wallpapers unless Active Desktop was activated. Could be wrong, though; hadn't used XP for years.

Comment: @pepoluan Have you used BgInfo? It's a corporate tool for organizations to specify the wallpaper in use and apply information to it. It works with XP+ and W2K with kernel modifications. It might not work with a JPG, but it should be trivial for them to convert to a BMP and apply that. Since Active Desktop disappeared with Vista, they would have needed to do something like this anyways to future proof

Comment: @InterLinked did you notice that this question you're commenting on was posted **more than seven years ago**? **January** 2013 to be exact. And when was BgInfo released for the first time? **August** 2013. So BgInfo was 7 months too late to solve my problems _at that time_.

Comment: @pepoluan What on earth are you talking about? BGInfo is more than 15 years old. It was around ***well before 2013***. Fact check yourself.

Comment: You might want to consult these links: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo and https://web.archive.org/web/20170905231332/http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/bginfo - BgInfo was in use as early as 2005, possibly much earlier.

Comment: @InterLinked okay, I stand corrected. Does not change the fact that this had been a very old question, situations have definitely changed, and whatever problems encountered here should no longer apply to any current situation (esp. since XP has been EOL-ed for years).

Comment: Not sure why you're so opposed to good or useful other information. Other people may find it useful. It doesn't matter if you don't care about XP anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being this is a GPO issue have you thought about just asking IT to fix it? Being domain admins they can do things like temporarily turn off your GPO rules and get it fixed a lot easier than you your self could.

I know as a techy myself it can be hard to just ask somone else to fix something for you on your computer, but sometimes you just got to go IT and get stuff fixed.

Comment: *sigh* ... that means, the recovery has to wait until I get back at the office... oh well :/

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Right click anywhere on the desktop, choose Properties.

On the Desktop tab, just click a different Background then click the original (corporate) one.
Windows will think you made a change (although you didn't) so the Apply button becomes active. Hit it (or the OK button), message will be gone.

Other (suggested) solution: Open Regedit, drill down to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\Components` and set the value for DeskHtmlVersion to 0.

That last one didn't work for me because after a restart (or logout/login), the value was back to 0x00000110 (272).

Do you have your system set to automatically log you in? I do, and see the white screen occasionaly, too.. maybe twice a week. If you really need the auto-logon, use the workaround above (just 6 mouse clicks).

Comment: unfortunately, that menu had been disabled via GPO. So I really can't change it via menu. *BUT*... your registry trick might've worked. The 'problem' is that I've left Windows XP and is now using Windows 7, which up to now has not (yet) had the problem :)